# Using one-class svm with malicious training data

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a large number of malicious executables and I want to use a one-class classifier to distinguish them from the other executables.. I cannot use the normal svm classifier as I have a huge imbalanced data(more malicious ex), therefore, is it possible to use one class SVM like the Novelty Detection [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/doc/modules/outlier_detection.rst) ?
I know it usually works by determining the normal behaviour but I want the other way around for other reasons .. do you have any recommendation ?

I am using Scikit learn implementation for the Svm classifier now ... And my data consist of 6000 malicious and 1000 non malicious

Comment: the definiton of "novelty" is completely up to user. The only underlying assumption is that the class you try to model has some underlying structure (thus it is not just a random noise).

Comment: What do you mean by "executables"? It will be pretty hard to do machine learning on binary code. Hence, how do your feature vectors look like. One-class svms are typically used to find the abnormal behaviour. Hence, I'd say you can use it. However, your question needs a bit reformulation.

Comment: The features in my case are text that usually used for malicious activity .. I want to use the" one svm classifier" where : the inlier is the malicious behaviour .. The outlier is the normal one ... And i was askinh if that is acceptable ?because its the other way around to what anomaly detection do

Comment: Yes this is perfectly valid. Insider/outsider in one class SVM is only a matter of perspective. it has nothing to do with malicious/not malicious.

Comment: You are treating non-malicious code as an anomaly? I would think the problem would be reversed. Can you provide the number of malicious vs non-malicious samples you have?

Comment: What SVM implementation are you using?  Scikit, Apache ML, libSVM, TrustedAnalytics, ... ??

Comment: @Prune Iam using Scikit learn implementation. ..look at my question I have add more details

Answer (score 1):

A 1-class SVM is simply looking for a boundary between two classes.  In theory, it doesn't matter which is the outlier; your inversion is logically sound.

In practice, I've occasionally found better results when I use the better-defined class as the inlier, provided I'm using an advanced kernel (e.g. Gaussian).  That little bit of guidance seems to help the chosen algorithm to converge more reliably on a better solution.  This shouldn't be the case; perhaps my feeling is merely observation bias.

---

Yes, evolving classification is a well-known problem with a wide variety of counter-measures.  The problem is called [drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_drift).  You'll need to educate yourself on the concept and research a approaches that address your application.

Once you've done that, if you still have open issues, you should post a separate question in this group.  It's a different topic, and your paradigm is presently too broad for a StackOverflow question.

Given that you're trying to identify malicious samples as being of a well-defined class, you may well get the better result with your desired method.  However, note that the benign code is also well-defined: absence of *any* trigger phrase.  To me, this seems the better definition: your malicious code class is actually the union of disjoint or loosely-connected classes, each characterized by a particular trigger phrase.

I would base this decision on which visualization is most convenient for the person doing the work: you.  Since you seem to like having the "any hot" side be the distinguishing factor, I suggest that you go with it.  If you have any doubts, try training your model each way, and see if there are differences with the implementation you're using.

Comment: The problem with the malicious that it is continusley evolving ... This will affect the classification then right ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it but:

- One-class SVM is an outlier detection method and unsupervised technique. Meaning it seperates an area of your training data INCLUDING outliers (anomalies/malicious instances).

This  means that to work you should have a quite "pure" dataset,
preferable use only the "good" data.

Also keep in mind that ANY unsupervised method will underperform a supervised one (more knowledge == reduced entropy for  possibile outliers )